# LESS : SyntaxError: error evaluating function `lighten`: a.toHSL is not a function

Tags: less

This code

```
.test { color : lighten( red, 10% ); }
```

is ok, but

```
@color : red ;
.test { color : lighten( @color, 10% ); }
```

results in

> SyntaxError: error evaluating function `lighten`: a.toHSL is not a function

Comment: [Works for me](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40color%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%5Cn.test%20%7B%20color%20%3A%20lighten(%20%40color%2C%2010%25%20)%3B%20%7D%22%7D). Is the closing `}` missing in your actual code or is that a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps due to the missing closing curly bracket `}`?

```
@color : red ;
.test { color : lighten( @color, 10% );}
```

When I [test](http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/xOBjNz) it with the bracket it works great :)

Comment: solved it, one of  my color name in english is incorrect ( im bat at english ), 
just forgot the closing bracket when copied .